# « Je ne t'ai vu prendre cette photo ! » ou « Je t'ai vu pas pris cette photo » ?

Tags: verbes, participe-passé, infinitif

Je tiens à m'assurer que je demande et conjugue de la bonne façon. 
Mon amie m'a montré une photo, qu'elle a prise quand nous sommes partis en voyage et je veux lui dire que je ne l'ai pas vue quand elle a pris cette photo.
Une suggestion ?

Comment: Always put ne-pas around the conjugated verb -- in this case the *ai* conjugation of *avoir*. So another example would be *Je ne vais pas aller* -- NOT *je ne vais aller pas.*

Comment: « Je t'ai vu pas pris cette photo » (hormis la faute de conjugaison), voudrait dire que tu as *vu* ton amie ne pas prendre de photo. Donc, que tu l'aurais vu ne pas se servir de son appareil en quelque sorte. Ce qui est différent de la situation que tu décris.

Answer (score 6):

> Je ne t'ai pas vu**e** prendre cette photo !

est la bonne solution.

Ici le verbe avoir s'accorde avec le COD placé avant car il est aussi sujet réel de la proposition infinitive.

Bref, ce n'est pas le sujet. Pour vous aider, le verbe « voir » est déjà conjugué au passé composé, le verbe suivant (ici prendre) sera donc à l'infinitif.

Comment: Bonjour,
pouvez-vous m'expliquer ça " le COD placé avant car il est aussi sujet de la proposition infinitive" où est ce COD ?
Merci

Comment: @downloaddowload
Le " t' " représente le COD. Le COD est l'élément répondant à la question "qui/quoi"?

La phrase basique est "Je n'ai pas vu". Le " t' " répond à la question "Qui est-ce que je n'ai pas vu?"

La proposition infinitive est le reste de la phrase, elle répond à la question "faire quoi?" : prendre cette photo

Comment: Merci infiniment pour la réponse

Answer (score 1):

La formulation correcte (langage courant) est:

> Je ne t'ai pas vue prendre cette photo!

ou plus familièrement (à l'oral):

> Je t'ai pas vue prendre cette photo!

Comment: Alors, j'étais presque correcte! :P Merci!

Comment: Petite remarque grammaticale : je pense qu'il faut accorder le participe passé au féminin vu qu'on parle ici d'une amie, qui prend la photo (=> Sujet du verbe prendre). Petite remarque typographique : sauf erreur, en Français le point d'exclamation doit être précédé d'un espace.

Comment: @LaurentS: Les conventions typographiques ne sont pas partout les mêmes. En particulier au québec il n'est pas habituel d'ajouter des espaces avant les ponctuations hautes.

Comment: @LaurentS. J'ai corrigé ce point, merci :) Concernant les espaces, en effet ce n'est pas une obligation, j'ai donc gardé la forme initiale (même si je préfère personnellement mettre un espace...)